# Populating UseState value with trpc response

Tags: typescript, react-hooks, trpc.io

I'm trying to populate the UseState initial value to the values of my users first and last name according to the response I got from the tRPC api.

```
    const { data: sessionData } = useSession();

    const { data: currentUser } = api.user.get.useQuery(
        undefined, // no input
        { enabled: sessionData?.user !== undefined }
    )

    const [formData, setFormData] = useState({
        firstname: "",
        lastname: "",
    });

    const updateUser = api.user.update.useMutation()

    const handleInput = (e: { target: { name: any; value: any; }; }) => {
        const fieldName = e.target.name;
        const fieldValue = e.target.value;

        setFormData((prevState) => ({
            ...prevState,
            [fieldName]: fieldValue
        }));
        console.log(formData)
    }
```

I first initiate the state of both `firstname` and `lastname` to be an empty string.

In my form I then the default value `currentUser?.user?.firstname` and `currentUser?.user?.lastname` those values are set displayed correctly on the form input fields.

[image]

When I only change one of the fields the other remains an empty string because `handleInput` has not been called on that field, therefore never updating the input value to what the `defaulValue` is. When I then submit the form, the input that was never changed is overwritten to a blank string in the database.

Any way we can correct this behavior to that when `currentUser` is no longer null, we change the `formData` from a blank string to the correct value?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the form input value is bound to the state value, a crude way to do this that will need a little refinement is to use a useEffect on the `currentUser` value:

```
    const { data: sessionData } = useSession();

    const { data: currentUser } = api.user.get.useQuery(
        undefined, // no input
        { enabled: sessionData?.user !== undefined }
    )

    const [formData, setFormData] = useState({
        firstname: "",
        lastname: "",
    });

    useEffect(() => {
        if(currentUser)
            setFormData({
                firstName: currentUser.firstName,
                lastName: currentUser.lastName
            })
    ), [currentUser]);

    const updateUser = api.user.update.useMutation()

    const handleInput = (e: { target: { name: any; value: any; }; }) => {
        const fieldName = e.target.name;
        const fieldValue = e.target.value;

        setFormData((prevState) => ({
            ...prevState,
            [fieldName]: fieldValue
        }));
        console.log(formData)
    }
```

Adding a loading state and only displaying the fields when the data is loaded will help. You might also want to move the state into a child component and initialise it when the data is loaded via props.

```
    const { data: sessionData } = useSession();

    const { data: currentUser, isLoading } = api.user.get.useQuery(
        undefined, // no input
        { enabled: sessionData?.user !== undefined }
    )

    if(isLoading)
        return (<div>Loading...</div>);
    else if(currentUser)
        return (
            <UserForm
                firstName={currentUser.firstName}
                lastName={currentUser.lastName}
            />
        );
```

Answer (score 0):

I figure out a way to do this, but I don't know if there is a better way of doing so.

Here is my solution:

```
    useEffect(() => {
        setFormData({
            firstname: (currentUser && currentUser?.firstname) || "",
            lastname: (currentUser && currentUser?.lastname) || "",
        })
    }, [currentUser]);
```